# LED holder modification

Tags: led, rgb

I'm working on a project where I will be using a bunch of RGB LED's. I bought a quantity of this style of LED holders:

[image]

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11147

The way they work is you slide the LED in the threaded end of the holder and then insert the plastic plug behind the LED and that holds the LED in place. The problem I'm having is that the plug only has enough space for the two prongs of a standard LED. With my 4 prong RGB LED it is not compatible.

If I wasn't concerned with being able to remove the LED from the holder or drying time is there some material that I could pour in behind the LED to take the place of the plug? I'm sure it would need to be non-conductive. Basically I'm thinking I can put the metal holder face down, drop the LED in, and then pour some glue, epoxy, etc in behind it to fill the rest of the cavity. This would prevent the prongs from touching each-other as well as keep the LED in place. I just don't know what type of material would work for this application.

Alternatively does anybody know where I could find an LED holder for a RGB LED?

Comment: Try potting compound. It's an epoxy that flows just enough that you can pour it.

Comment: You bought a bunch of LED holders *before* knowing whether they were appropriate for your LEDs!!?

Comment: I bought them when I thought I was going to use standard colored LED's, was still in the planning phase, and needed to get to the $20 minimum for an online order. I needed colors that were difficult to find in single color LED's and later found out about RGB led's which I didn't know about previously. So my plan changed from single color LED's to RGB leds. Thus the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hot Glue, or quick set Epoxy. Most are non-conductive, and you don't need a lot.

Or you can just use a exacto knife and cut a line in the plastic plug. Or use a needle.

Comment: I tried cutting the plug but it didn't work well. I basically would have to cut into the sidewall to get enough space. Hot glue would be ideal since I could get just the right amount and it's cheap. It wouldn't damage the LED?

Comment: Hot glue is a very low temperature glue. The plastic around the led was extruded on when it was a lot hotter. Hot glue won't do anything bad to a led. And when you cut it, i mean just straight down, not like in half. You just want to make the holes for the pins. @William

Comment: Ok cool. I'll use the hot glue then. Yeah I tried cutting with an exacto and using a drill but neither really did much that would work for the quantity I need to do. The problem is that the 4 pins are 90% the width of the LED so even if I went straight down and only carved out exactly what was needed for the pins I'd still be hitting the side walls of the plug. Thanks for the help.